# salesforce trigger code coverage stuck at 35% no matter what i do

Tags: triggers, salesforce, code-coverage

hi i am new to saleforce apex codiing and i have written a trigger which on lead conversion trasnfers  a custom object to both the account and contact.(deals/offer). i have written the trigger and the test code for it but i am stuck at 35% code coverage can u please point out where i am going wrong

here is the trigger that i have written

```
trigger TransferDeals on Lead (after update) {
Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
Lead parent;

for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++){
if (Trigger.new[i].IsConverted == true && Trigger.old[i].isConverted == false) {
  leadMap.put( Trigger.new[i].Id, Trigger.new[i]);
}
}

if( leadMap.size() > 0 ) {
  Set<Id> leadIds = leadMap.keySet();
  List<Deal_Offer__c> allChildren = 
    [select Id, Account__c, Contact__c, Lead__c from Deal_Offer__c where lead__c in :leadIds];

System.debug(allChildren);

  for ( Deal_Offer__c child : allChildren ) {
    if ( leadMap.containsKey( child.Lead__c ) ) {
       // lookup the parent lead
       parent = leadMap.get( child.Lead__c );
       // update the fields on the child object
       child.account__c = parent.ConvertedAccountId;
       child.Contact__c = parent.ConvertedContactId;
    }
  }

System.debug(allChildren);
//try {
update allChildren; 
// } catch( Exception e ) {
      // could put something here to notify on error
     // otherwise it fails silently
// }
```

}
   }

and here is the test class that i have writen to validate the code

```
@isTest
private class Leadtriggertest {
static testMethod void verifyAccount(){
    // Perform our data preparation.
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>{};
    List<Deal_Offer__c> deals = new  List<Deal_Offer__c>{};  
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        Lead a = new Lead(LastName = 'TestLead ' + i,Company = 'TesCompany' + i,IsConverted=false);
        Deal_Offer__c b = new Deal_Offer__c(Name = 'TestDeal' + i,Lead__c = a.Id);
        leads.add(a);
        deals.add(b);
    }
    insert leads;
    insert deals;

    Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
    Set<Id> leadIds = leadMap.keySet();
    List<Lead> allChildren = [select Id,LastName,IsConverted from Lead where Id in :leadIds];
        for ( Lead child : allChildren ) {
            if(child.IsConverted==false){
                child.Isconverted = true;
            }
        }

    // Start the test, this changes governor limit context to 
    // that of trigger rather than test. 
    test.startTest();

    // Insert the Account records that cause the trigger to execute.
    update Leads; 

    // Stop the test, this changes limit context back to test from trigger.
    test.stopTest();

    List<Deal_Offer__c> testdealsupdate = 
                              [select Id, Account__c, Contact__c, Lead__c from Deal_Offer__c where lead__c in :leadIds];
    List<echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c> testagreementupdate = 
                            [select Id, echosign_dev1__Account__c, echosign_dev1__Recipient_Lead__c from echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c where echosign_dev1__Recipient_Lead__c in :leadIds];
    List<Lead> leadcheckout =
                             [select Id,LastName,ConvertedAccountId,ConvertedContactId from Lead where Id in :leadIds];
    Map<Id,Lead> leadmap2= new Map<Id,Lead>();

    for(Lead c: leadcheckout){
        leadmap2.put( c.Id, c);
    }
    for(Deal_offer__c a : testdealsupdate){
        Lead b = leadMap2.get(a.Lead__c);
        System.assertEquals(a.Account__c,b.ConvertedAccountId);
        System.assertEquals(a.Contact__c,b.ConvertedContactId);
    }
    for(echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c a : testagreementupdate){
        Lead b = leadMap2.get(a.echosign_dev1__Recipient_Lead__c);
        System.assertEquals(a.echosign_dev1__Account__c ,b.ConvertedAccountId);
    }

}
```

}

please help me figure out how to increase the code coverage thank you in advance

Comment: Don't write code to improve code coverage; write tests that provide value i.e. what is it you want the code to do properly/correctly? Write those tests and then see how your coverage improves. Any code not covered ask yourself "what does it do?", "what is it's purpose?" and write tests that exercise the purpose and not the implementation.

Comment: I agree with @Shaun Wilde. Try and list different scenarios that will execute different branches in your trigger.

Comment: will definelty try this approach..thanx for the quick replies...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because this part of the code is not being executed (or rather the if condition in there).

```
for ( Deal_Offer__c child : allChildren ) {
if ( leadMap.containsKey( child.Lead__c ) ) {
   // lookup the parent lead
   parent = leadMap.get( child.Lead__c );
   // update the fields on the child object
   child.account__c = parent.ConvertedAccountId;
   child.Contact__c = parent.ConvertedContactId;
}
```

Can you verify by adding an system.debug statement in the if statement?
Also, try printing out all of the lead id's in the map, and the corresponding `child.Lead__c` value that you are using in the line `leadMap.containsKey (child.Lead__c)`.

Anup

Comment: anup,Shaun...the trigger is working perfectly in the sandbox... i have to test *the lead on conversion operation* in the test class and i think i am writing that test logic wrong. can please guide on how to test for such scenarios preferable a bulk trigger test. Thank you. cause when broke the code down i wasnt able to set the isConverted to true on updating in test trigger.